# Multiclass confusion matrix in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm trying to create a **single** multiclass confusion matrix in Python.

```
df_true = pd.DataFrame({
    "y_true": [0,0,1,1,0,2]
})

df_pred = pd.DataFrame({
    "y_pred": [0,1,2,0,1,2]
})
```

And I want a **single** confusion  matrix that tells me the actual and predict value for each case. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Why the emphasis on **single**? Do you have examples of "multiple" confusion matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to make a confusion matrix plot. This can be done with [`sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.plot) using the result from [`sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).

```py
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import pandas as pd

df_true = pd.DataFrame({
    "y_true": [0,0,1,1,0,2]
})

df_pred = pd.DataFrame({
    "y_pred": [0,1,2,0,1,2]
})

cm = confusion_matrix(df_true.y_true, df_pred.y_pred)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,
                              display_labels=[0,1,2],)
disp.plot(cmap="Blues")
```

[image]

Comment: cant believe i did not realize about this